# Android - setting up guidelines in the camera

Tags: java, android, camera

I was wondering if there was a way to add a vertical and horizontal yellow lines in the middle of the width and length respectively on the camera, so that the user has a rough guideline when making the photo. I can post code if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just have to use OverLay for the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code may help your:

```
final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));
dialog.setContentView(R.layout.guideline);
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
//for dismissing anywhere you touch
View masterView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.guidelineView);
masterView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
});
dialog.show();
```

Comment: How do I overlay this onto the camera?

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/12/add-overlay-on-camera-preview.html this link may help you